# ID auto-increment when inheriting from TimeStampedTable

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-2.0

Django 2.0.8 & Azure SQL Server

I have a TimeStampedModel from which all of my other tables inherit created_at and updated_at.

It appears that TimeStampedModel_PTR_ID is the ID for each table. This number increments for each record inserted in to ANY table.

That is,

> Insert one record into Table 1, TimeStampedModel_PTR_ID = 1
>
> Insert 300 records into Table 2
>
> Insert one record into Table 1, TimeStampedModel_PTR_ID = 302

I have one table that will have many records. While I may not run out of numbers, the non-consecutive IDs bother me.

Is this normal behavior?

Did I do something incorrectly?

Is this something I can correct?

Do I need to NOT inherit like this? (i.e. explicitly add created_at and updated_at to each model)

Do I need to explicitly add an id to each model and mark it as primary_key?

Thank you.

---

In SSMS, SQL Query...

SELECT ID from TABLE fails - no ID field
SELECT PK from TABLE fails - no PK field

select * from TABLE shows:

TIMESTAMPEDMODEL_PTR_ID     NAME
439                         Lorem Ipsum

(only 1 record in this table)

`Base Model`

class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

`Model that Inherits that Base Model`

class Organization(TimeStampedModel):

```
name = CharField(_("Name of Organization"), blank=True, max_length=255)
role = CharField(_("Role of Organization"), blank=True, max_length=255, choices=ORG_ROLE_CHOICES)
```

I expected that each model/table would have its own auto-increment counter. It appears that there is one counter for all tables in the db.

Comment: UPDATE: I removed TSM from one other model. When I went to migrate, it is asking me to provide a default for ID. I assume this means that the model was getting its ID from TSM, hence, one auto-increment counter for for all subclasses of TSM.

Comment: UPDATE: Inserting a record fails because I cant supply an ID.

 
('INSERT INTO [projects_projectdomain] ([timestampedmodel_ptr_id], '
 '[parent_project_id], [parent_domain_id], [score]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)')

I'm rebuilding this without TimeStampedTable.